# delphi, DevExp cxGrid записать переменные в грид

Tags: delphi, devexpress

В форме имеются несколько элементов edit.

Как передать в `cxGrid` значение этих edit-ов?
(БД не использую!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делаю так:

```
var          
  Index : Integer;
begin
  Index := View1.DataController.AppendRecord();
  View1.DataController.SetValue(Index, ColumnName1.Index, 'Some Value');
  View1.DataController.SetValue(Index, ColumnName2.Index, 'Some Value2');
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш ответ помог!

Comment: @djoni Я рад что ответ помог. Тогда отмечаем ответ как решение ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Можно вот так:

```
tvcxgrd1TableView1.Columns[0].EditValue := edt1.Text;
```

или так:

```
tvcxgrd1TableView1.DataController.Values[0, 0] := edt1.Text;
```